# ActionScript stage browserZoomFactor error

Tags: actionscript, flash, stage

When using this.stage.browserZoomFactor, compilation gives

```
Error: Access of possibly undefined property browserZoomFactor 
through a reference with static type flash.display:Stage.

        return this.stage.browserZoomFactor;
```

Which is unfortunate, as I cannot find any examples online where anyone actually uses browserZoomFactor. Not sure how to go about fixing this issue, but all suggestions are welcome.

Relevant code snippet:

```
public function getZoomLevelInfo():Number {
        return this.stage.browserZoomFactor;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're on IE, Windows 8, this feature won't work. Other browsers don't report the browser zoom amount, so that property will not be found.
http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2014/09/improved-resolution-of-stage3d-content-on-browser-zoom.html

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using this in a static reference.
make sure that stage is not null before you call its properties.
if stage is defined, then stage.browserZoomFactor should work just fine.

try the following code:

```
if ( stage === null ) trace("stage is null, it's a scope issue");
else trace("zoom factor:", stage.browserZoomFactor);
```